# Access query with date BETWEEN breaks when using parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL query in access that will grab all records where a calculated date is in between two values. It works fine if I hardcode date literals such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE DateAdd("d",-60,DateAdd("yyyy",65,[Table].[BirthDate])) Between #3/21/2021# And #3/27/2021#;
```

However I need to parametrize the the between dates so that they can be entered by a user like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE DateAdd("d",-60,DateAdd("yyyy",65,[Table].[BirthDate])) Between [StartDate] And [EndDate];
```

However when I run the latter query and enter the exact same dates as the former, hard-coded one, it starts pulling records outside the between range. I've attempted to enter the dates like `3/21/2021` as well as date literals like `#3/21/2021#` and neither work. The latter doesn't pull anything at all.

I also have a form with a handful of text boxes using the short date format that let the user pick the dates for the query. It has the same issue of pulling back incorrect records. None of the records have any time component to my knowledge.

How can I get the date between to correctly work with user entered parameters?

Comment: Been a long, LONG time since I've used Access, but think that the dates still need the `#`? ... such as `#[StartDate]#`, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't seem to work. The query wont run and complains about a syntax error like that.

Comment: The parameters work for me. I never use dynamic parameterized query. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report. If you must use dynamic parameters then should reference controls on form for input. Input via popup prompt cannot be validated. SQL injection is a definite risk with user-typed input. Use comboboxes and listboxes when possible.

Comment: Correction, no errors but not getting correct record output either. My other comments still apply.

Answer (score 1):

Access doesn't know what data type your parameters are, so specify that in the query:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    StartDate DateTime,
    EndDate DateTime;
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    Table
WHERE 
    DateAdd("d",-60,DateAdd("yyyy",65,[Table].[BirthDate])) Between [StartDate] And [EndDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters worked to filter a native field - not the calculated date. However, using CDate() function worked.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE DateAdd("d",-60,DateAdd("yyyy",65,[Table].[BirthDate])) 
      Between CDate([StartDate]) And CDate([EndDate]);
```

But before I remembered that, I tested calculating with inputs back to a birthdate range which also worked.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE [BirthDate] Between DateAdd("d",60,DateAdd("yyyy",-65,[StartDate])) 
                      And DateAdd("d",60,DateAdd("yyyy",-65,[EndDate]));
```